# Openerp Record Rule

Tags: odoo, record, rule

How to make a record rule with boolean field, i got this error

File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/expression.py", line 757, in parse
field_path = left.split('.', 1)
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'split'

I tried this:

```
[(user.partner_id.supplier,'=',False)]
```

Comment: You have done wrong. For a domain, its 3 parts are actually field_name, condition and value.Here you have used value as the first part of the domain which is wrong. To which model you want to add this record rule?

Comment: a model of my own. I would like to show records only for certain users what belong to group logged with same state of user_id. Also, if user is not supplier would show all records.

Answer (score 0):

try

`[('user.partner_id.supplier','=',False)]`